# Произвести распараллеленный поиск по ненаправленному графу в ширину

Tags: c, многопоточность, графы

Произвести распараллеленный поиск по ненаправленному графу в ширину.
Как его сделать многопоточно?

P.S.
Граф задается набором значений, что хранятся в вершинах, и набором пар связей.

Comment: А как вы его сделали однопоточно? И как именно представлен в памяти граф (какая структура используется)? Запрос в поисковик типа "параллельный поиск в ширину граф" выдаёт немало реализаций. Остаётся лишь адаптировать их под свои нужды.

Comment: Я нашел только https://studbooks.net/2075732/informatika/poisk_shirinu_mnogopotochnaya_versiya

Comment: А вот на Си многопоточной реализации ни одной больше не нашел

Comment: Да и на плюсы тоже ...

Comment: Ну, алгоритм есть. Перевести на конкретный язык - чисто механическая работа.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если бы там был весь алгоритм, а не куча воды с щепоткой указаний, я бы его реализовал, а не просил бы о помощи

Comment: Описали бы все же (в виде структур Си) представление графа. А то, не совсем понятно в  чем именно проблема (и лучше этот момент тоже словами проясните)? Где при обходе создавать новый поток?, как возвращать результат поиска?, как сообщить другим потокам, что поиск пора завершать?, делать ли пул потоков?, использовать joinable или detached?, или вообще не знаете, как запустить поток

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишем **рекурсивную** функцию, которая имеет один аргумент - вершину графа, от которой будет плясать.

В теле функции выполняем три действия:

1. Составляем список всех соседей
2. Для обработки каждого соседа создаём нить
3. В нити рекурсивно вызываем саму же функцию, передавая ей в качестве параметра очередного соседа.

Что должна возвращать такая функция и как - это уже Вам виднее.

Comment: Попробую - отпишусь

Comment: Это поиск в глубину